# Как передать данные между дочерними компонентами?

Tags: angular2, angular, angular4

Подскажите как передать данные между дочерними или совсем не родными компонентами?
Вроде как можно через сервисы, но немогу понять логику как прописать.
К примеру мне нужно передать дату из одного компонента в другой.

Comment: еще пытаюсь вникнуть в эти советы, пока не могу сказаьт помог или нет, разбираюсь=)

Answer (score 7):

Данные между передавать разными способами, можно изолировать логику в сервис, но это уже прибегание к декомпозиции. Можно через байндинги и генераторы событий (`EventEmitter`), а можно через нативный диспатчинг. Представьте себе такое дерево:

```
-- app-calendar
  -- app-events
    -- app-event-list
      -- app-event
```

Мы хотим передать данные из компонента `app-event` в `app-calendar`, как бы это выглядело с применением генератора событий?

```
-- app-calendar (подписывается на генератор из `app-events`)
  -- app-events (подписывается на генератор из `app-event-list` + создает свой генератор для `app-calendar`)
    -- app-event-list (подписывается на генератор из `app-event` + создает генератор для `app-events`)
      -- app-event (создает генератор для `app-event-list`)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В конечном итоге нам нужно в трех компонентах на разном уровне создавать генераторы, это будет похоже на макароны. Можно избежать этого используя обычное всплытие событий, например мы хотим компонент `app-calendar` слушать событие `toggleEvent`, который диспатчит `app-event` (находится в самом низу дерева). Для этого мы инжектим ссылку на самого себя в компонент `app-event` и диспатчим событие:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-event',
  template: `
    <p>Пойду ли я на это событие? - {{ event.status }}</p>
    <button (click)="toggleEvent()">Изменить статус</button>
  `
})
class EventComponent {
  @Input()
  public event: CityEvent = null!;

  constructor(private host: ElementRef<HTMLElement> {}

  public toggleEvent(): void {
    const event = new CustomEvent<CityEvent>('toggleEvent', {
      detail: this.event,
      bubbles: true <-- magic :)
    });

    this.host.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
}
```

P.S. В IE11 нужно использовать `document.createEvent('CustomEvent')` + `initCustomEvent(...)`.

В шаблоне компонента `app-calendar` (который на самой верхушке дерева) мы можем сказать `EventManager`'у слушать это событие:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar',
  template: `
    <app-events (toggleEvent)="toggleEvent($event)"></app-events>        
  `
})
class CalendarComponent {
  public toggleEvent({ detail }: CustomEvent<SystemEvent>): void {
    console.log(detail);
  }
}
```

Заметьте что `app-event` находится внутри `app-event-list`, но событие может всплыть до `app-calendar`. Это все работает благодаря зоне и компилятору, результатом работы компилятора будет оптимизированный JavaScript код, в котором будет содержаться уже готовая информация для инициализации директивы:

```
<app-events (toggleEvent)="toggleEvent($event)"></app-events>
                              |
                        AOT компилятор
                              |
elementDef(..., ..., ..., 'app-events', ..., ..., [['toggleEvent']] <-- свойство `outputs`)
                              |
                    Angular 8 (компилятор Ivy)
                              |
elementStart(index, 'app-events', attrs);
listener('toggleEvent', (event) => componentInstance.toggleEvent(event);
elementEnd();
```

Поэтому в рантайме компонент, а точнее обертка поверх компонента (`ViewDef`), знает какое событие слушать, псевдокод ниже:

```
const events = document.querySelector('app-events');
events.addEventListener('toggleEvent', (event: CustomEvent) => {
    viewDef.componentInstance.toggleEvent(event);
});
```

В случае с новым Angular и Ivy компилятором - в рантайме обработчик события регистрируется сразу после создания элемента `app-events`, для этого используются R3 инструкции и инкрементальный DOM.

Я предпочитаю этот вариант, так как он избавляет меня от выделения большого количества памяти. Потому что:

- `Observable` - 96 байт
- `Subject` - 96 байт
- `EventEmitter` - 104 байта
- `Subscription` - 104 байта
- `Subscriber` - 104 байта
- `Event` - 56 байт
- `MouseEvent` - 40 байт

Это большая цепочка наследования, вот только каждая сущность имеет свою бизнес логику. `EventEmitter` это абстракция поверх `Subject`:

```
class EventEmitter extends Subject ...
```

Единственная разница - это возможность асинхронного генерирования событий:

```
new EventEmitter(true <-- `__isAsync`);
```

Поэтому в случаях если `__isAsync === true` - `next` просто оборачивается в `setTimeout`.

Второй вариант это общение через сервисы. Общение через сервисы было заложено еще в бете второго Angular, так как Мишко предложил SCA (service-component architecture). Реализация очень простая, сервис создает какой-то генератор событий:

```
public events$ = new Subject<unknown>();
```

Компоненты подписываются на этот генератор, а также вручную гененируют какие-то события через:

```
service.events$.next(что-то);
```

Как пример есть компоненты, которые вообще находятся в разных модулях, но при клике на какую-то кнопку нужно скрывать сайдбар, как это реализовать с использованием сервиса?

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class SidebarService {
  public sidebarShown$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
}
```

`BehaviorSubject` - это генератор, который кеширует последнее событие.

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <app-sidebar *ngIf="sidebarShown$ | async"></app-sidebar>
  `
})
export class SomeComponentOnSomeLevel {
  public sidebarShown$ = this.sidebarService.sidebarShown$.asObservable();

  constructor(private sidebarService: SidebarService) {}
}
```

В компоненте другого модуля инжектим также этот сервис и генерируем событие на клик:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <button (click)="toggleSidebar()">Toggle sidebar</button>
  `
})
export class AnotherComponentOnAnotherLevel {
  constructor(private sidebarService: SidebarService) {}

  public toggleSidebar(): void {
    const shown = this.sidebarService.sidebarShown$.getValue();
    this.sidebarService.sidebarShown$.next(!shown);
  }
}
```

Когда таких сервисов много есть большая вероятность столкнуться с энтропией и single responsibility начинает подхрамывать.

Самый лучший вариант, хоть вы и новичок, но все равно должны попробовать это в действии - Redux :) Redux - это архитектурный шаблон, который позволяет уменьшить связь между компонентами системы за счет одностороннего потока данных, поступающего из одного хранилища. В Angular есть много инструментов для Redux, такие как `NgRx`, `NGXS`, `Akita`, `redux-observable`. Redux дает возможность DDD и масштабируемость. Есть вот такая диаграмма, она отражает Redux-ориентированное приложение.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если когда нибудь созреете, то советую вам [эту статью](https://medium.com/@overthesanity/ngrx-ngxs-%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4-%D1%81-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B-b03c11c3d529), она даст вам небольшой экскурс в самые популярные инструменты для Redux в Angular.